Regular expression which can only Mask 4 digit from right
Regular expression which can only Mask 4 digit from right.
It should include space as well but should only mask digit

EX- 12345 1234 1234 mask should be 1234 1234 ****
Ex- 12345678 Mask should be 1234****
Ex- 12345 5467 Mask should be -- 12345 ****
Ex- 12345 678  Mask should be -- 1234 * ***

I tried below
(?<=\d{4})\d{4}\b

It masking 4 digit from right but failing when there is space in digits
Tried below as well but not got what I want
(?<=\d[\d\s]{3})\d(?=\s*\d\s*\d\s*\d\s*\d\b) (?<!\d)(?=(?:\D*\d){4}\D*$)\d

Can any one please help me for same.

Replace \d(\s*)\d(\s*)\d(\s*)\d(\s*)$ with *\1*\2*\3*\4.  This will do nothing if there are fewer than 4 digits at the end.
